Which jurisdictions require suppliers of software for encrypted communication to provide source code to the authorities?
It appears that in France, the supply of software which enables encrypted communication is only allowed provided that the government sees the source code. Article 30(III) of the "Law No. 2004-575 of June 21, 2004 for confidence in the digital economy" says (translated from French):

The supply, transfer from a Member State of the European Community or import of a means of cryptology not exclusively ensuring authentication or integrity control functions are subject to prior declaration to the Prime Minister ... The supplier or person carrying out the transfer or import shall make available to the Prime Minister a description of the technical characteristics of this means of cryptology, as well as the source code of the software used

Which other democratic jurisdictions, if any, impose such (or stricter) requirements on the supply of software for encrypted communication?
Bonus question: does the quoted law mean that, for example, WhatsApp provides its source code to the French government?

Do you know that access to the source does not particularly facilitate decryption? Nothing secure can depend upon secrecy of the source code or algorithm.

@GeorgeWhite I know. How is that relevant? I am not asking about providing access to the communication itself. Take the question at face value please.

@GeorgeWhite Nonetheless source code is quite valuable for spotting, for instance, foreign-owned backdoors in your cryptosystems.

There are many types of encryption that are completely open source and anyone who wants to can look at it.

@JoeW The most interesting code is the closed one.

Many would disagree with you on that, and the main reason I can think of that they would want to view the code is to make sure it is actually encrypting as advertised. As I mentioned many encryption methods are open source and anyone can look at the code which is done to ensure that is is encrypting as advertised and doesn't have any vulnerabilities.

Anything getting its security by a secret algorithm has a big vulnerability to the secret becoming known.

@JoeW The overall law claims to be about "confidence in the digital economy". So I think you're probably right -- we want to ensure that it encrypts as claimed, and doesn't have deliberate backdoors that would undermine the security.

@JoeW How looking at some open source code can possibly give any confidence that a particular closed code does the same?

Where did I suggest that looking at open source code gives you confidence about what closed sourced code does? What I said is that people look at open source code so that they have confidence that it does what it says in regards to encryption and that is likely why governments want to review closed source code that makes claims about encryption.

@JoeW I don't understand the purpose of your comment at all then. The question is not "why" but which (other than French).

I understand that the question isn't asking why but that doesn't mean understanding why something is being done isn't important.
