What is the law regarding declaration of cryptology services and tools?
The French Prosecutor has released details of the investigation resulting in Pavel Durov's arrest, which ends with these three points:


Providing cryptology services aiming to ensure confidentiality without certified declaration,
Providing a cryptology tool not solely ensuring authentication or integrity monitoring without prior declaration,
Importing a cryptology tool ensuring authentication or integrity monitoring without prior declaration.


What are these declaration requirements?  In particular, could they extend to individuals downloading and hosting cryptographic tools and services like mastadon servers, tor nodes and public blockchains?

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/104680/which-jurisdictions-require-suppliers-of-software-for-encrypted-communication-to
